# Xamarin Insights not enabled after upgrading to Xamarin 6.0.2(Build 73)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

On previous versions of Xamarin Studio, I can upload my dsym file to Xamarin Insights before app submission.

But now, after upgrading to OSX El Capitan 10.11.5 (15F34) and Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 (Build 73) I am getting "Insights not enabled" after archiving my application.

My Xamarin Insight implementation hasn't changed and it worked previously. Is there anything else I need to do to enable Xamarin Insights in this Xamarin Studio version?

Edit:

This is what's shown in Archive:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried going through this once again https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/getting-started/ ?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. It was working on Xamarin Studio 5.10.3.51 when I last submitted my app to the App Store.

Comment: no i mean after upgrading have you tried following that steps? sometime upon update some setting gets reset!

Comment: Yup, I've followed the steps. Added the Nuget package, added the initialize in the main file. Still displayed as Not Enabled. I've even created a new project to see if that would work, but I'm still getting Insights not enabled.

Comment: Mine shows the same thing.  Just installed it in VS2017 for Mac within a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Forget Xamarin Insights, use http://mobile.azure.com (docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/sdk/crashes/xamarin)